# What causes a transport layer error in Excel when querying an SSAS cube?

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

We've just started getting this error while filtering and slicing a pivot table in an Excel workbook (the pivot table is connected to a SQL Server Analysis Services cube on another server):

[image: Excel an error was encountered in the transport layer]

> We couldn't get data from the external source. Here's the error
>   message we got:
>
> An error was encountered in the transport layer.

The error only occurs after a couple of minutes of editing of one workbook on one computer - we have not reproduced it on any other computer or with any other workbook, even if connecting to the same SSAS machine and querying the same cube. However, the affected user can recreate the problem more or less on demand by downloading another copy of this particular workbook from our SharePoint, opening it in their local Excel and changing the slicer selections for a few minutes.

The affected user is connecting to our company network via a VPN, which I suspected at first but ruled out due to the error only occurring with this one workbook.

I have found a variety of postings about the same error message that were the result of authentication problems, but I don't believe that is the case for us as the same user is able to access the same cube from the same computer via another workbook without any errors, and is able to use this workbook for several minutes before the error occurs. However, the error does eventually occur while using this workbook.

I found a post with a very similar set of symptoms where the cause turned out to be an anti-virus application blocking the port being used after a period of being idle (see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/29bd2921-25cd-47d7-8850-5e5498c6eff4/intermittent-error-an-error-was-entountered-in-the-transport-layer-when-using-a-slicer-in-excel?forum=sqlanalysisservices), but we have excluded Excel from this computer's Kaspersky with no success.

I can't find any errors in the SSAS log, even when using SQL Profiler to capture the traffic. I can't find any relevant errors in the event log on the server either.

How should we go about troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. This issue only happens on one particular machine. What makes it harder to diagnose is that it used to work just fine, so I doubt it's the firewall.

Answer (score 2):

We had an issue which ended up being a saved password which was held in Credentials Manager, once this was corrected the pivot table could be refreshed

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @ianlee50 - our errors were only coming after several minutes of using the connection successfully, but if it happens again I'll check Credential Manager just in case.